# SQL How to group a table with special condition and join to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

i have Table PRICE

```
CodePrice  CodeClient  TheZone Tempo W_Begin W_End Price
A_0_49       88989       1       1      0      49   20
A_50_99      60000       1       1      50     99   10
B_0_49       88989       2       1      0      49   30
C_0_49       50000       3       4      0      49   40
```

Table Ordre

```
  NoID  CodeClient    Cp   Agence  TheZone Tempo Weight 
    01      88989     44   bidon      1      1     12
    02      60000     49   toto       2      2     10
    03      60000     49   bigoi      1      1     56
    04      88989     49   titi       3      3     8
    05      50000     44   bidon      1      1     5
```

How can i show the result like this:

```
CodePrice   TheZone Tempo W_Begin W_End  SUm_Weight  SUM_Price  CountIDOrdre  CP   Agence
  A_0_49        1       1      0      49       17         40          2         44    bidon
  A_50_99       1       1      50     99       56         10          1         49    bigoi
  B_0_49        2       1      0      49       0          0           0         null  null
  C_0_49        3       4      0      49       0          0           0         null  null
```

in 1 SQL Syntax (1 Step).

Nowdays i make it in 2 step

```
SELECT CodePrice
      ,CodeClient
      ,TheZone         
      ,Tempo   
      ,W_Begin
      ,W_End
      ,Price          
  FROM PRICE
  LEFT JOIN T_TARIF_ZONE ON PRICE.ZONE = T_TARIF_ZONE.NO_ID     
  LEFT JOIN CLIENT ON PRICE.CodeClient= CLIENT.CODE_CL     

  WHERE CodeClient= @NO_CLIENT AND TheZone = @ZONE AND UNITE = @UNITE 
  AND (Tempo   IN (SELECT ParsedString From dbo.ParseStringList(@ModLiv)))

  ORDER BY MONTANT
```

after i select the price, now i can group the ordre on each price depends on Weight, zone, and another variable

```
SELECT count(NoID) as LVId            
      ,sum(Weight)as Tot_Poids        
      ,sum(Price) as Tot_Prix      

  FROM [Ordre]
  WHERE Weight>= @TR_DEB AND Weight<= @TR_FIN AND LE_ZONE = @LE_ZONE AND ENLEV_UNITE = @ENLEV_UNITE 
        AND DATE_CLOTURE >= @Date_Deb AND DATE_CLOTURE <= @Date_Fin AND STATUT_LV = 2 AND FACTURATION = @FACTURATION

  HAVING count([NOID]) > 0
```

Comment: 1) What RDBMS is this running on, as this may require vendor-specific implementation (SQL Server?)? 2) `SUM_Price` in your 'desired' results example doesn't make any sense; it appears to potentially be for _weight_, but I can't tell how the results are supposed to be summed.  3) You're going to have to be more specific on how the table are supposed to be joined together, because you don't list all columns in the tables that you list in the SQL Statements (although some of those may be untranslated - please make up your mind).

Comment: Thanks you for responding,
1. SQL Server 2008 R2 Express
2. i have made a correction
3. the rest of the column is not important, i use left join just to show label

Comment: Still not enough, you still haven't qualified what columns (from the first query) are supposed to be the inputs for the second query.  And we're still missing some referenced columns in those queries (didn't notice you're _also_ leaving out some **tables**, first time around).  Please either remove all references to 'unimportant' columns, or add those columns (and the missing table definitions).  And _please_, make sure all reference names match.